# Python. Почему у max() пустой аргумент при сортировке списка методом выбора?

Tags: python, list, сортировка, max, сортировка-выбором

помогите пожалуйста с сортировкой выбором на питоне:

```
a = [78, -32, 5, 39, 58, -5, -63, 57, 72, 9, 53, -1, 63, -97, -21, -94, -47, 57, -8, 60, -23, -72, -22, -79, 90, 96, -41, -71, -48, 84, 89, -96, 41, -16, 94, -60, -64, -39, 60, -14, -62, -19, -3, 32, 98, 14, 43, 3, -56, 71, -71, -67, 80, 27, 92, 92, -64, 0, -77, 2, -26, 41, 3, -31, 48, 39, 20, -30, 35, 32, -58, 2, 63, 64, 66, 62, 82, -62, 9, -52, 35, -61, 87, 78, 93, -42, 87, -72, -10, -36, 61, -16, 59, 59, 22, -24, -67, 76, -94, 59]
n = len(a)
for j in range(n):
    tmp1 = a[n - j - 1]
    a[n - j - 1] = max(a[0:n - j - 1])
    a[a.index(max(a[0:n - j - 1]))] = tmp1
print(a)
```

Пытаюсь искать максимальный элемент списка в определённом диапазоне, чтобы его переместить. Попробовал срезы, но, видимо, неправильно. IDE говорит, что у max() пустой аргумент:

> File "C:\Users***********\main.py", line 5, in < module >

> a[n - j - 1] = max(a[0:n - j - 1])

Подскажите, что исправить.

Comment: Да, при определённом значении j получится пустой срез.

Comment: Спасибо, додумался!

Comment: Нужно было убрать '-1' в местах аргумента для max(), ведь, как и говорил @Эникейщик, если будет последняя итерация цикла, что получится пустой срез [0:0]. Тема закрыта.

Answer (score -1):

```
n = len(a)
for j in range(n):
    tmp1 = a[n - j - 1]
    a[n - j - 1] = max(a[0:n - j])
    a[a.index(max(a[0:n - j]))] = tmp1
print(a)
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]